# Binary Counter Amortized Analysis

Tags: algorithm, analysis, amortized-analysis

I guess you already know that if all the entries in the Array starts at 0 and at each step we increment the counter by 1 (by flipping 0's and 1's) then the amortized cost for k increments is O(k).

But, what happens if the Array starts with n ? I though that maybe the complexity for k increments is now O(log(n) + k), because of the fact that in the beginning the maximum number of 1's is log(n).

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. There is more than one way to prove this, one of them is with a potential function. [This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_method) (and many others) explain the potential method. However, textbooks usually require that the initial value of the potential function is 0. Let's generalise for the case that it is not.

For the binary counter, the potential function of the counter is the number of bits set to 1. When you increment, you spend k+1 time to flip k 1's to 0 and one 0 to 1. The potential decreases by k-1. So the amortised time of this increment = ActualTime+(PotentialAfter-PotentialBefore) = k+1-(k-1) = 2 (constant).

Now look at the section "Relation between amortized and actual time" in the wikipedia link.

```
TotalAmortizedTime = TotalActualTime + SumOfChangesToPotential
```

Since the SumOfChangesToPotential is telescoping, it is equal to FinalPotential-InitialPotential. So:

```
TotalAmortizedTime = TotalActualTime + FinalPotential-InitialPotential
```

Which gives:

```
TotalActualTime = TotalAmortizedTime - FinalPotential + InitialPotential <= TotalAmortizedTime + InitialPotential
```

So, as you say, the total time for a sequence of k increments starting with n is O(log n + k).

Comment: This is incorrect; the amortized cost is O(k). Sorry for the (extremely) late comment and downvote; I saw this answer in a link from another question. (As you yourself note, the amortized cost for a single increment is constant.)

Comment: He asked what happens when "Array starts with n". Let's say n=2^d-1 for some large d and k=1, i.e., only one increment operation. The operation will take time Omega(d), which is not O(k).

Comment: Yes, "amortized" complexity does not predict the cost of doing a single computation, by definition of "amortized". You're providing an example for "worst-case" complexity.

Comment: What I said it true for any k << d, not only k=1. Amortized complexity is, to be accurate, about proving the worst case complexity for a sequence of operations.