# Analysis of the complexity of incrementing binary counter with a given initial content

Tags: algorithm, binary, complexity-theory, counter

The key is that the binary counter has some content at the beginning. Is it still amortized constant time complexity? How to prove it?

Let's say that we have `11010` binary counter and we increment it so it's now `11011` and so on.

What is the amortised cost of single increment operation?

Comment: Can you clarify your question with the help of an example?

Comment: Yes. Let's say that we have 11010 binary counter and we increment it so it's now 11011 and so on. What is the amortised cost of single increment operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The amortised cost of each operation is O(1).

Let `n` be the number of bits in the counter.

```
In all increment operations, you need to change the LSb
In half of the operations, you need to change the 2nd LSb
In 1/4 of the operations, you need to change the 3rd LSb
...
In 1/(n/2) of the operations, you need to change the (n-1)th LSb (2nd MSb)
In 1/n of the operations, you need to change n'th LSb (MSb).
```

This gives you average performance of:

```
1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ... + 1/n <=(*) 2
```

To formally prove it, use induction, in the number of bits modified.

---

(*) is from [Sum of geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum), with `a=1, r=1/2`, when summing from 1 to infinity we get `SUM = 1/(1-r) = 1* 1/(1/2) = 2`. Since we only reduced from this number we actually got that the sum is strictly smaller than 2.

Comment: and isn't it nlogn? I found similar discussion but I don't get it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191641/binary-counter-amortized-analysis

Is it constant or nlogn?

Comment: @user2513816 It is constant. This is sum of geometric series. See edit.

Comment: Hm... I'm still not convinced since you proved the amortized complexity for 0 initialized binary counter. What I am wondering about is: does complexity of increment operation changes when we are provided with let's say a counter initialized with 25 i.e. 11010 and not with 00000. Does it change the result?

Comment: @user2513816: Look at that answer. It is phrased (correctly) in terms of "changing bits", which implies that the previous value of the bit is irrelevant to the complexity. In short, no, where you start doesn't change the amortized complexity.